# External Links Open Within My Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have come across a problem which is quite confusing.

When I use this line of code:

```
<li><a href="www.google.com" style="margin-right: 40px;">Donate</a></li>
```

The site 'www.google.com' opens in my window or tab with this URL: https://gyazo.com/6f200273b542d4f91e202a85bc3bc725

It does the exact same thing if I add

```
target="_blank"
```

to the code too

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need `http://` before the `www`.

Comment: You might have some browser plugins installed, Try it on a incognito widow?

Answer (score 1):

as mention in comments above you need `https://`

```html
<li>
  <a href="www.google.com" style="margin-right: 40px;">without https</a>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" style="margin-right: 40px;">with https</a>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_Blank" style="margin-right: 40px;">https with target blank</a>
</li>
```